# Git branches results comparison

Tags: git

I have a project giving as output couple of tables. I need to optimize it verifying on each step that output tables are equal or at least the difference is explainable.

So I created two branches and the idea is iteratively modifying the code in one branch then run both and compare the results at the end. Apply the modification of the last commit of the first branch to the second branch, modify the first one again and so on ...

How could I reapply the last modifications of one branch to another with no merge of previous commits?

Comment: Why use branches? Commit each time and `git diff HEAD^...HEAD`.

Comment: They stock results and logs in different directories to make comparison easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to simply keep the commits linear in the first place.  If you want to use two branches walking that line of commits, that makes some sense; but by having two lines of commits you're creating unnecessary work.

From comments, I infer that you have some baseline configuration changes, affecting output directories and such.  Managing those configurations within the code such that you need to persist a code change to redirect output is a design mistake, and the problem you're facing here is a symptom.  You'd get more bang for your buck by fixing that issue.  Then you can simply start both branches at the same commit, make the changes and commit them to the test branch, run your test; if it passes, merge (using fast-forward) the change into the main branch, and if not, roll the test branch back.

But if you're determined to spend one-off effort instead (and still have this design flaw waiting to trip you up the next time you want to do something), then you can instead do what you're doing, and then cherry-pick the `HEAD` commit from the test branch onto the main branch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Note that at least 9 times out of 10, if I mention cherry-picking it's to call it the most over-recommended command in git.  The closest related operations (which I prefer when they're applicable) are rebase and squash merge; but neither one works quite the way you'd want in this case.  To me, that's further evidence that the design isn't right to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please propose a design solution or you need more info? I

Comment: I probably don't have enough information to go into any real detail; but things like output directories could presumably be put in a configuration file, which could either be selected/populated as part of the build process or provided at runtime.  From there, many variations are possible. You could keep "test" and "main" versions of the config both in source control. Or you could keep just a template in source control and supply specific values form outside git.  You could maybe even just make the paths relative and check out main and test to separate work trees. Depends on your project